# How do i get the entered pin in TVDigitEntryViewController's completion handler in TVOS?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I read about 'TVDigitEntryViewController' in AppleTV OS document. They are given completion handler but i don't know how to use. Share your knowledge if you know.

Answer (score 2):

Text for the entry could be retrieved in `entryCompletionHandler`

Try using below code to add `TVDigitEntryViewController` on your view controller.

```
func addDigitEntryComponent() {
        let digitEntryViewController = TVDigitEntryViewController()
        digitEntryViewController.isSecureDigitEntry = true
        digitEntryViewController.view.backgroundColor = .gray
        digitEntryViewController.titleText = "New PIN"
        digitEntryViewController.promptText = "Please enter new PIN"
        digitEntryViewController.entryCompletionHandler = { (enteredText) in
            // Text will be received here in variable "enteredText"
            print(enteredText)
        }
        self.addChild(digitEntryViewController)
        digitEntryViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(digitEntryViewController.view)

        digitEntryViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        digitEntryViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        digitEntryViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        digitEntryViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        digitEntryViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Mohnish.